# IE - styleSheet.addRule ignored when printing?

Tags: javascript

I'm setting some css rules dynamically in IE8 using the addRule() method. I'm finding that when I print, these rules are getting ignored - whether I'm adding the rules to a print specific stylesheet or not.

Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Can you provide the code in question?

Comment: While trying to put together a simple html page that demonstrates the issue, I couldn't reproduce it. Then I realized it was because I was using an inline <style> element. Hence, my self-answer below. And I can't give you the example code because as I said, it only breaks on an external style sheet. But try it yourself with a simple page with an external stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is only the case for external style sheets - workaround is to use an inline <style> element instead.